# SD Card shield and TCRT5000 sensor aren't working together on arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, sd-card, current

I need to work with SD card and `TCRT5000 sensor` (Reflective Optical Sensor with Transistor Output) and save data from sensor to file. So I select `Arduino Uno` and added to it a SD card shield(from LC STUDIO) and a `TCRT5000 sensor` but it isn't working.
My circuit and code is here:
[image]

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 10;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  File dataFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  dataFile.close();
  dataFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if(dataFile){
    dataFile.println("Start:");
  }else{
    Serial.println("Error in creating file.");
    while(true);
  }
}

void loop() {
  float value = analogRead(A3);
  File dataFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println(value);
    Serial.println(value);
    dataFile.close();
  }else{
    Serial.println("Error in opening file.");
  }
  delay(5);
}
```

When `TCRT5000` isn't connected SD card working without any problem.
I think it is related to current and supply current. Any idea?

Comment: I would like to believe that you made a mistake with +5 and GND from board???

Comment: 60mA can not do any problem. Maybe you connected it wrong? 90% problems are in wiring :))

Comment: I checked it again. The circuit isn't wrong. I do it like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-DIY-SD-Card-Logging-Shield/?ALLSTEPS) and [this](http://blog.huntgang.com/2014/06/17/arduino-tcrt5000-build-ir-sensor/). If problem is not related to current,it is related to what? Why the SD card work when I remove `TCRT5000` from circuit without any change in wiring?

Comment: Try disconnecting only D+. That way you know if the problem is with the IR-diode or the phototransistor.

Comment: The 5V to the breadboard power rails is 100% not in the right spot. Both the 5V and GND are in the same rail, causing a short. I assume this is just an error in the diagram, like @Martynas said?

Answer (score 1):

Did you figure this out yet? If not, you have the +5 volts going to the GND on the breadboard, causing a short.